# Using If Statement in Prime Membership (Python)

Tags: python, if-statement

I'm using trying to understand this project where I need to use if statement to make sure those with prime membersihp gets free shipping. The below is what I have done so far and my idea. I'm getting an error with my code and I was wondering how I can improve it. I'm not quite sure how to incoroporate any order over $50 is shipped for free.

A certain website allows its customers to pay an annual fee to become a “Prime member”. Prime members get free shipping. In addition, any order over $50 is shipped for free.

Write a program that asks whether the user is a member and the amount of the purchase, and tell them whether or not shipping will be free.

```
membership = float(input("Are You A Member? Y or N"))
if memembership= Y:
    print("There is a $0 charge for luggage that heavy.")
print("Thank you for your business.")
```

Comment: Why are you calling `float()` for a `Y` or `N` input?

Comment: `=` is for assignment, `==` is for comparison.

Comment: @Barmar, should I just take the float out? I would like to use the if statement because I need to ask a question if the customer has the membership, but I'm not quite sure how and why to incorporate the $50 shipped for free if members get free shipping.

Comment: @Barmar, also are you saying that I need == and not =? Isn't it = since it's a statement? Yes, I do have membership so I get free of charge shipping?

Comment: The first line is an assignment, it sets `membership` to what the user entered, so you use `=`. The second line is a comparison, you want to know whether `membership` contains `Y` or not, so you should use `==`.

Comment: If you don't understand this, you need to go back to your textbook and brush up on the basics. You can't write a program if you don't know basic syntax.

Comment: When you aren't sure what's going on, break the program into smaller steps and apply a liberal number of print statements. For instance, `answer = input("Are You A Member? Y or N")` followed by `print(answer)` gives you an idea of what those statements are doing.

Answer (score 0):

There were a couple things wrong with your code.

1) Your membership input statement should *stay* as a string, not be casted as a float

2) An equality statement in python requires 2 equals signs `==` not `=`

Also, if you want to check one condition *or* another condition you should use an `or` clause to check it in your if statement.

As for telling the user whether or not the shipping is free, try to figure that one out on your own. It shouldn't be too tricky.

```
membership = input("Are You A Member? Y or N")
order_price = int(input("Input the price of your order: ")
free_shipping = False
if memembership == "Y" or order_price >= 50:
    free_shipping = True
print("Thank you for your business.")
```

Comment: thank you very much for your input? How would I put if statement for N? or does that or order_price line will take care of that?

Comment: @python2learn you don't need to because if membership is "N" and the price is less than 50 free shipping is automatically set to `False`

Comment: Understood thank you so much for your help. You really help me clarify and understand the functions.